# How do I access a subproperty from my .resw file in code?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

How do I access "properties" of my `.resw` resource file in code?

---

For example, take this example RESW file (from MSDN):

[image: screenshot of resw editor, with properties like 'Greeting.Text' and 'Farewell']

I can access `Farewell` easily:

```cpp
auto resourceLoader{ Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView() };
const auto myString = resourceLoader.GetString(L"Farewell");
```

But if I try to do the same thing with `Greeting.Text` (which automatically sets the `Text` property of a control with `x:Uid="Greeting"`, so I can't change it), my app crashes:

```cpp
auto resourceLoader{ Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView() };
const auto myString = resourceLoader.GetString(L"Greeting.Text"); // crashes
```

Can I access this resource in code without duplicating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can!

Just replace the `.`s with `/`s:

```cpp
auto resourceLoader{ Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView() };
const auto myString = resourceLoader.GetString(L"Greeting/Text");
```

### Further information

XAML calls resources that correspond to properties on a control **property identifiers**: whereas `Farewell` can only be loaded manually, from code, `Greeting.Text` corresponds to a property on a control (and is automatically applied to any control with the `x:Uid="Greeting"`.

These property paths seem to be encoded as URIs, so you have to switch from `.` to `/` when accessing them in code.

MSDN describes that behavior on [Localize strings in your UI and app package manifest#Refer to a string resource identifier from code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest#refer-to-a-string-resource-identifier-from-code):

> If a resource name is segmented (it contains "." characters), then replace dots with forward slash ("/") characters in the resource name. Property identifiers, for example, contain dots; so you'd need to do this substitution in order to load one of those from code.
>
> ```cs
> this.myXAMLTextBlockElement.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("Fare/Well"); // <data name="Fare.Well" ...> ...
> ```
>
> If in doubt, you can use [MakePri.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options) to dump your app's PRI file. Each resource's uri is shown in the dumped file.
>
> ```xml
> <ResourceMapSubtree name="Fare"><NamedResource name="Well" uri="ms-resource://<GUID>/Resources/Fare/Well">...
> ```